# need to change wp_query in wordpress for search

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to customize search in wordpress so search will look for keywords in postmeta table also. I put meta_query varaible for the wp_query variable. The output of query is below for wp_query object:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON        (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
```

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_parent = 0  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%4422%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%4422%')))  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'wpsc-product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'CAS #' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%4422%')
OR  (mt1.meta_key = 'style' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%4422%')
OR  (mt2.meta_key = 'Packaging' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%4422%') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 75

Now issue is that it is looking in both post & postmeta table.So if keyword is not in post_content or post_title and not in meta fields, nothing is coming.

I need this to look in anywhere in post_content, post_title & meta fields so it finds value in any of these, it will show the result. right now it is showing

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,'meta_key'=> KEY_TO_SEARCH, 'meta_value'=>$search_value, 'post_type'=> 'post','orderby' => 'post_date','order' => 'DESC','post_status' => 'publish',  'posts_per_page' => $post_to_show);
 query_posts($args);
```